# Pause a WebKit animation on hover

Tags: css, animation, css-animations

I'm trying to get an animation to pause on mouse over with the following:

```
.quote:nth-child(1):hover {
    -webkit-animation-play-state: paused;
    -moz-animation-play-state: paused;
    -o-animation-play-state: paused;
    animation-play-state: paused;
}
```

But it does not want to pause.  Can anybody see what I'm doing wrong?

[**JSFIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/j4Abq/)

Answer (score 70, accepted):

Instead of:

```
.quote:nth-child(1):hover 
{
    -webkit-animation-play-state: paused;
    -moz-animation-play-state: paused;
    -o-animation-play-state: paused;
    animation-play-state: paused;
}
```

use:

```
.quote-wrapper:hover .quote 
{
    -webkit-animation-play-state: paused;
    -moz-animation-play-state: paused;
    -o-animation-play-state: paused;
     animation-play-state: paused;
}
```

**DEMO**: http://jsfiddle.net/j4Abq/2/

Comment: Thanks Tom.  That works almost perfect.  The problem that I'm finding is that if I don't let each of the quotes cycle before hover/pausing it seems to mess up the animation.  I've tried moving the hover command around (a shot in the dark) but that doesn't help.  Any ideas?

Comment: This will just pause the animation at whatever state it is in, I'm not sure what you could do to change that. Maybe try asking it as a new question? Good luck.

Comment: Thanks Tom!  That seems to have fixed the problem.

Comment: You should also use: 
-ms-animation-play-state: "paused";
for IE8 and IE9.

Comment: This comes I adapted this answer and **at first** it wasn't working in any browser. (I'm trying to make a `.paused` style applied with javascript on mouseover of many separate elements. In my case, I simply needed to add `!important` to the end of each line. Since people may use your answer for similar purposes, you might add that to your answer, so that it's more prominent than a comment. 
`animation-play-state: paused !important;`

Answer (score 9):

I can see that a solution appeared to be found. However, I offer another easy solution to the problem of pausing an animation AND resetting to the start.

In order to 'pause' and go back to the initial state of the animation, use:

```
<selector>:hover {
    animation: step-end;
}
```

I had an animation running that was infinitely changing font color from dark to light, and when I hovered over it using 'step-end', the animation paused and instantly switched to the initial dark color, then resumed when the pointer moved away.

Hope this may help others. :-)